# insert query error #1054 unknown column in field list but the column exists

Tags: mysql

I've been getting this error

> Error-1054 Unknown column 'column name' in 'field-list'

while trying to insert values into a table, the column does exists and I have checked and there are no blank spaces on the name.

This is the mysqli statement

```
INSERT INTO tblsemaforos(idSemaforo, idUsuario, fecha, averia, observaciones, estatus) 
                     VALUES('1','4', '2022-05-29 17:20:36', 'Wrong turn', 
                            'test4', 'Reported')
```

And I get this error:

> Error description: Unknown column 'idUsuario' in 'field list'

as you see the column idUsuario does exits in the table, why Im getting this error?

Comment: It is visible that you account for the `idUsuario` field in your insert sql, but are You sure that the field exists? What is the result of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblsemaforos;` command?

Comment: Thank you your comment made me realize that I was pointing to the wrong table!

Comment: FYI mysqli is a PHP extension. What you are asking about is the SQL language, probably MySQL flavour.